# Activity extended from CameraBridgeViewBase (OpenCV) doesn't make camera connection

Tags: android, opencv

I made an activity extended from `CameraBridgeViewBase` (OpenCV). When `mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();` is called, it should display the camera. But now it is not.
My activity is as follow

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String  TAG                 = "OCVApplication::MainActivity";
    public static final int      VIEW_MODE_RGBA      = 0;



    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;

    public static int  viewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;

    private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }
}
```

The xml is

```
<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"        
        android:layout_above="@+id/ImageCaptureButton"
        android:id="@+id/image_manipulations_activity_surface_view"
        opencv:show_fps="true" 
        opencv:camera_id="any"/>
```

Comment: In logcat all message have you find some log that help to find the problem?

Comment: LogCat messages are alright. Just show those related to loading OpenCV lib are OK.

Comment: i've download opencv sample for the *cameraPreview* the only relevant difference between code is this function:`public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }`

Comment: i'm welcome ;) wait to your up vote!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed this:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
   return inputFrame.rgba(); 
}
```

Hope this help!